# How do I plot two Pandas Series on a single plot figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two Series with the same indices and need to plot their values on the same plot, each as a line plot.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(numkdhh_pmf.index, numkdhh_pmf.values, ax = axs, color = 'r')
sns.lineplot(biased.index, biased.values, ax = axs, color = 'b')
plt.show()
```

This only shows the latter plot, whichever is written second. Any thoughts on why both plots refuse to show on the figure?

The values of both Series are on a similar scale, so it isn't a zoom issue.

EDIT

The two plots show when omitting the fig, axs set up according to the below code. I'm still not sure why as I don't have a thorough understanding of Seaborn/matplotlib. The code is indeed being run from Jupyter but it was always in the same cell. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
ax2 = sns.lineplot(biased.index, biased.values, color = 'r')
sns.lineplot(numkdhh_pmf.index, numkdhh_pmf.values, ax = ax2, color = 'b')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you put together a simple example with two small example Series that reproduces the problem? I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnZwinck your dupe was my first reflex for the question, but if you take a closer look you'll see that this one is about standalone calls to seaborn, which _should_ use the same figure. The alternative that the dupe is about would produce two figures, whereas in this case there's only one figure and one of the plots is lost.

Comment: Alex, does anything change if you overwrite `axs = sns.lineplot(...)` from the first call? I don't think this should be necessary but the docs of `lineplot` ominously says "_Returns the Axes object with the plot drawn onto it_".

Comment: Andras, this change works but only if `fig, axs = plt.subplots()` is removed as shown in my edit. I don't know why but thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's weird :) But as long as it works...! No problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your code works fine for me as it is, here is another alternative you can try. `sns.lineplot` returns an axis instance (let's call it `ax1`) which you can pass to the second lineplot. I chose some fake data to provide answer.

```
data = np.random.random((10))
ax1 = sns.lineplot(data, data, ax = axs, color = 'r')
sns.lineplot(data+0.5, data+0.8, ax = ax1, color = 'b')
```

[image]